# How to count items in list recursively

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am looking to count the items in a list recursively. For example, I have a list few lists:

```
a = ['b', 'c', 'h']
b = ['d']
c = ['e', 'f']
h = []
```

I was trying to find a way in which I find out the length of list 'a'. But in list 'a' I have 'b', 'c' and 'h' ... hence my function then goes into list 'b' and counts the number of elements there... Then list 'c' and then finally list 'h'.

Comment: Do these lists consist of strings, or other lists? Your example uses strings, but your question implies you mean lists. Or are you trying to map the strings to the other lists?

Comment: okay think of it like a binary search tree... each node is connected with a node previous to it... and each node may have more than 1 node attached to it..

Comment: so I guess the  'b', 'c', 'h' are for example nodes .. and to "node" b, 'd' is connected to it

Comment: do you want the total length including the length of the sublists?

Comment: In that case do you want the length of `a` to include the lengths of its children?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham .... Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = ['d']
c = ['e', 'f']
h = []
a = [b,c,h]

def recur(l):
    if not l: # keep going until list is empty
        return 0
    else:
        return recur(l[1:]) + len(l[0]) # add length of list element 0 and move to next element

In [8]: recur(a)
Out[8]: 3
```

Added print to help understand the output:

```
def recur(l,call=1):
    if not l:
        return 0
    else:
        print("l = {} and  l[0] = {} on recursive call {}".format(l,l[0],call))
        call+=1
        return recur(l[1:],call) + len(l[0])
```

If you want to get more deeply nested lists you can flatten and get the len():

```
b = ['d']
c = ['e', 'f',['x', 'y'],["x"]]
h = []
a = [b,c,h]
from collections import Iterable

def flatten_nest(l):
    if not l:
        return l
    if isinstance(l[0], Iterable) and not isinstance(l[0],basestring): # isinstance(l[0],str) <- python 3
        return flatten_nest(l[0]) + flatten_nest(l[1:])
    return l[:1] + flatten_nest(l[1:])


In [13]: len(flatten_nest(a))
Out[13]: 6
```

Comment: If the list contains strings that reference the name of the children lists, you can access them with locals()['list name'] too

Comment: Please give me a sec to understand this.. and then i will comment if I have questions.

Comment: @Parker, yep, I just presumed the OP actually has a list of lists

Comment: @Ali, add a `print(l)` in the code before the if statement and it will make more sense

Comment: @PadraicCunningham .. okay I am finally understanding this code properly.

Comment: @Ali, I added a print statement to make it more transparent

Comment: @PadraicCunningham .. okay a question just arised.. What If I had the len of sub-sub lists... for example if in the above example h=['y'] .. but there was a y = ['z', 'x']

Comment: you mean lists of lists of lists...?

Comment: yeah i guess.. kind of like a family tree with descendants.. each element in a list represents children and each child may have their own children. which is then represented by a list

Comment: so you just want the total length of all items in all sublists?

Comment: yes sir indeed. so even if it is like sub-sub-sub lists.

Comment: it says basestring is not defined

Comment: use `isinstance(l[0],str)` for python 3

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was this:

```
def recur(arr):
 if not arr:
  return 0
 else:
  return 1 + recur(arr[1:])
```

Comment: This doesn't count the sub lists, and you could just call len()