# Recursive list count

Tags: python, list, recursion, count

I got a school assignment, where I need to count the number of lists in f.e. this list:

```py
['a', ['house', [2], 3], [], [[[2]]], 'b']
```

I can't wrap my head around on how to do it recursively, without using global. I would appreciate any kind of help you will be able to give me.

I tried doing this:

```
def zoznam_prvkov(zoznam):
    z = []
    for i in range(len(zoznam)):
        if isinstance(zoznam[i], list) == False:
            z.append(zoznam[i])
        else:
            zoznam_prvkov(zoznam[i])
    return z
```

But that returns only [1, 2, 3, 6, 8]

Comment: A hint, make a function that returns the number of list in a list ...

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Suggest you search first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455612/how-to-count-items-in-list-recursively may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item is not a list, then return `0`, otherwise count it as a list and sum up the counts of all the items:

```py
def count_lists(x):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        return 0
    return 1 + sum(count_lists(item) for item in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a recursive function in Python, which is basically the process of calling the function within the function itself.

```
def count(x: list):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return sum(count(item) for item in x) + 1
    else:
        return 0

lst = ['a', ['house', [2], 3], [], [[[2]]], 'b']

print(count(lst)) # 7
```